# using jquery animation with fadeout effect

Tags: jquery

I created some jQuery, which should do the following: when you hover inside the `div`, its contents will animate to the left or top, and then on mouseout it will come back to 0px and it will fadeout.

I was able to do it but it doesn't run smoothly when it gets to mouseout.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AufTr/

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".le").css("display", "block");
        $(this).find('.h1').animate({
            left: '-300px',
            top: '130px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).find('.h2').animate({
            left: '80px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).find('.h3').animate({
            top: '130px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.h2').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).find('.h3').animate({
            top: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
        $(this).find(".h1").animate({
            left: '0px',
            top: '0'
        }, "normal", function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.le').fadeOut('fast');
            }, 0, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            });
        });
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:200px;width:200px; margin:0 auto;" class="button">
<div class="h1 le" style="background:#CCCCCC; display:none; position:relative">
<img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/797/797108_300.jpg" width="300" height="300" border="0" alt="" /></div>
<div class="h2 le" style="background:#FF0000; display:none; position:relative">Responsive</div>
<div class="h3 le" style="background:#00FF00; display:none; position:relative">View</div>
```

​

Comment: It runs smooth on Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez: I'm on Chrome; I see the problem but its a subtle one. The smiling div seems to jump before fading out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a visual effect caused by the contrast between `.button` background color -green- and image's background color -white-.

Take into account that the browser is not a animation rendering engine. Firefox is even slower that Chrome. So even if you get to run smoothly your animation in Chrome, is not garanteed it will do smooth on other browsers or slower machines.

Please, try to change the `.button`'s `background-color` to white. You will notice the animation seems smoother.

I've forked your code. My code basically fadeout the smiling div while it is been returned to its original position. I looks smoother to the eyes. But I'm not sure if that kind of effect is what you want.

Link: [My fork on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrRamirez/2877S/).

PD.: I've added a `pointer-events: none;` CSS rule for `.le` class. This rule avoid the animated elements abort the animation while them pass below the mouse pointer.